# Make scrolling a sticky element higher priority than changing the element position

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a side nav, I want the side nav to be sticky so that it scrolls along with the user. However the side nav is not of a fixed height: when a user opens an item on the nav with sub items then it expands vertically to show the sub items.

Once a submenu expands, or I suppose on a small screen, the menu may not fit on one screen like before. The solution for a user would be to scroll down the page to see the bottom of the nav and select their chosen link. However now that the side menu is sticky, the menu will rather scroll with them when the scroll down. It's only once the user reaches the bottom of the content that the menu will then find the end of it's container and stay so the user can access the bottom of the menu.

Here is a [code pen](https://codepen.io/austingrey/pen/rPqOeP) I forked that illustrates the issue. The content is massive and the side nav only slightly larger than the screen height.

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  height: 120vh;
  min-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 3em;
}

.main {
  width: 60%;
  height: 2000vh;
  min-height: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.main,
.sidebar {
  border: 5px solid #222;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #222;
  padding: 15px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

body {
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
}

code, pre {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <h2>Main content</h2>
    <p>Scroll down the page!</p>
    <p class='bottom'>You made it!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Sticky sidebar</h3>
    <p>I will follow you! But should wait til you hit my bottom when scrolling down before following down. If you are scrolling up, I should wait for you to hit my top before following.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What can I do? I would love a pure CSS version for performance reasons. I dont want to limit the height of the nav because that means the vast majority of the users will need to rethink how they use the nav, by scrolling on the nav directly rather than on the content like they are used to.

I have found a JS library called [sticky kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) that creates the exact effect I am looking for, the scrollable sticky element example in particular. However it has not been updated in 2 years and I don't want to rely on a jquery plugin that likely will not work as web standards change.

There is a middle ground option, where I use JS to change the CSS sticky direction on scroll - like [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrLRvm). But there is a terrible jerkiness when you switch directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I have studied, this is just not part of the spec for sticky at this time - you need to use a bit of JS.

However how much JS can be minimized if you instead use the JS to control the sticky positioning. I forked that JS pen I posted at the end of my question and worked on it to find a very minimal solution with very little JS, that tries to avoid too many calculations on the scroll event listener.

```js
window.onscroll = function (e) {
  if (window.scrollY < this.prevScrollY) {
    // Track position state of nav
    // 1 == stuck to top
    // 0 == absolute positioning
    // -1 == stuck to bottom 
    this.stick_pos = scrollUpwards(this.stick_pos);
  } else {
    this.stick_pos = scrollDownwards(this.stick_pos);
  }
  this.prevScrollY = window.scrollY; 
}

function scrollUpwards(stick_pos) {
  // If the element is already stuck to the top then we are fine
  if(stick_pos === 1) return stick_pos;
  // Figure out where the new window will be after scroll
  let aside = $("aside").get(0);
  let aboveAside = aside.getBoundingClientRect().top > 0;
  // If we are going above the element then we know we must stick
  // it to the top
  if (aboveAside){
    $("aside").css("position", "sticky")
      .css("top", 0)
      .css("bottom", '')
      .css("align-self", "flex-start");
    return 1;
  }
  // If it will still be below the top of the element, then we
  // must absolutely position it to its current position - if it already is absolutely positioned then we do nothing
  if (stick_pos == 0) return stick_pos;
  
  // Undo the stick to the bottom
  // First get the current position
  $("aside")
    .css("top", aside.offsetTop)
    .css("position", "absolute")
    .css("bottom", '')
    .css("align-self", "");
  return 0;
}

function scrollDownwards(stick_pos) {
  /*
  let aside = $("aside").get(0);
  let aboveAside = aside.offsetTop >= window.scrollY;
  let browser_bottom = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
  let aside_bottom = aside.offsetTop + aside.offsetHeight;
  let belowAside = browser_bottom >= aside_bottom;
  if (aboveAside) {
    //console.log("stick to bottom");
    $("aside").css("top", ''); 
    $("aside").css("bottom", 0); 
    $("aside").css("align-self", "flex-end");
  }
  */
  // If the element is already stuck to the bottom then we are fine
  if(stick_pos === -1) return stick_pos;
  // Figure out where the new window will be after scroll
  let aside = $("aside").get(0);
  let browser_bottom = window.innerHeight;
  let aside_bottom = aside.getBoundingClientRect().top + aside.offsetHeight;
  let belowAside = browser_bottom > aside_bottom;
  // If we are going below the element then we know we must stick
  // it to the bottom.
  if (belowAside){
    $("aside").css("position", "sticky")
      .css("top", '')
      .css("bottom", 0)
      .css("align-self", "flex-end");
    return -1;
  }
  // If it will still be above the bottom of the element, then we
  // must absolutely position it to its current position - if it already is absolutely positioned then we do nothing
  if (stick_pos == 0) return stick_pos;
  
  // Undo the stick to the top
  // First get the current position
  // $("aside").css("position", "absolute")
  // .css("top", aside.offsetTop);
  $("aside")
    .css("top", aside.offsetTop)
    .css("position", "absolute")
    .css("bottom", '')
    .css("align-self", "");
  return 0;
}
```

```css
div#section {
  /* begin: irrelevant styling */
  margin: 5em auto;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  max-width: 300px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #dbe4ee;
  /* end: irrelevant styling */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
div#section div#nav-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 2em;
}
div#section div#nav-container aside {
  position: sticky;
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 2em; /* Magic number, must be same width as the aside nav */
  /* begin: irrelevant styling */
  background-color: #81a4cd;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
div#section div#nav-container aside div {
  padding: 0 .3em;
}
div#section article {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
div#section article p {
  margin: 0;
}
div#section article p + p {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='section'>
  <div id='nav-container'>
  <aside>
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>F</div>
    <div>G</div>
    <div>H</div>
    <div>I</div>
    <div>J</div>
    <div>K</div>
    <div>L</div>
    <div>M</div>
    <div>N</div>
    <div>O</div>
    <div>P</div>
    <div>Q</div>
    <div>R</div>
    <div>S</div>
    <div>T</div>
    <div>U</div>
    <div>V</div>
    <div>W</div>
    <div>X</div>
    <div>Y</div>
    <div>Z</div>
  </aside>
  </div>
  <article>
    <p>Perferendis ut iusto voluptatem ex temporibus aut autem amet. Sit vero in soluta. Est officia asperiores tenetur vel quam nostrum eum facere. Sed totam quasi libero at facilis doloremque. Non aut velit odio. Tempora dolore sunt recusandae sed quia
      sunt.</p>

    <p>Voluptatem optio asperiores dolorem voluptatem. Ipsa alias perspiciatis doloribus est nisi ut. Fuga aut et vitae consequatur dolor corrupti aut minima.</p>

    <p>Facilis et ut eligendi. Excepturi labore asperiores vero. Perferendis porro sunt molestiae. In sit dolorem eum esse sit inventore est. Atque perspiciatis commodi nihil.</p>

    <p>Consequatur ipsa id repellendus voluptatem perspiciatis temporibus. Praesentium eveniet nemo laudantium inventore similique impedit nihil esse. Maiores iste commodi molestiae quas odit nihil ex corrupti. Illum id amet non vero.</p>

    <p>Voluptas soluta itaque et. Aperiam quasi sint eos ullam. Assumenda facilis omnis alias numquam. Odio quia esse vel et minima soluta architecto. Qui saepe consequatur aut rerum. Et et aut voluptatibus inventore.</p>

    <p>Perferendis ut iusto voluptatem ex temporibus aut autem amet. Sit vero in soluta. Est officia asperiores tenetur vel quam nostrum eum facere. Sed totam quasi libero at facilis doloremque. Non aut velit odio. Tempora dolore sunt recusandae sed quia sunt.</p>

    <p>Voluptatem optio asperiores dolorem voluptatem. Ipsa alias perspiciatis doloribus est nisi ut. Fuga aut et vitae consequatur dolor corrupti aut minima.</p>

    <p>Facilis et ut eligendi. Excepturi labore asperiores vero. Perferendis porro sunt molestiae. In sit dolorem eum esse sit inventore est. Atque perspiciatis commodi nihil.</p>

    <p>Consequatur ipsa id repellendus voluptatem perspiciatis temporibus. Praesentium eveniet nemo laudantium inventore similique impedit nihil esse. Maiores iste commodi molestiae quas odit nihil ex corrupti. Illum id amet non vero.</p>

    <p>Voluptas soluta itaque et. Aperiam quasi sint eos ullam. Assumenda facilis omnis alias numquam. Odio quia esse vel et minima soluta architecto. Qui saepe consequatur aut rerum. Et et aut voluptatibus inventore.</p>
</div>
```

Its not ideal compared to a CSS solution but its pretty zippy and seems stable. I'm all ears for improvements and will be cleaning it up on the [codepen](https://codepen.io/austingrey/pen/YBRXMm). For one this solution makes use of magic numbers (the width of the aside container and the aside must be held the same, since the aside will be absolutely positioned during interim scrolls). This could be solved with a css variable I suppose.